# How to show toast in AsyncTask in doInBackground

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In one of my activities I'm using `AsyncTask`. In `doInBackground()` I'm making calls to various methods. In one of these methods I'm getting an exception, so in the catch block I want to show the error in the Toast.
I know I can use `Log`, but still I prefer Toast.
So, how can I use Toast in AsyncTask in doInBackground()?

Comment: why you are not retuning error to onPostExecute from doInBackground() and then so this error in a toast from onPostExecute

Comment: you can't modify the UI from the doInBackground() method, try to return some result, and test on that result in the onPostExecute() method , if it is , so show the Toast

Comment: @Sam : easy man !! i didn't voted down , i've just added my comment, i know that you can give access in `doInBackground()` , but it isn't recommended to do that, if so , then why there is methods `onProgressUpdate()` and `onPostExecute()` ??

Comment: Consider the user here. The real answer is that you probably shouldn't be throwing a Toast in the first place. As a developer it might be nice to see updates to whatever it is you are trying to do in the background. But does your *user* really care? You are fighting the framework when you try to update the UI from `doInBackground`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could wrap the Toast in [`runOnUIThread()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) but this isn't the best solution.
You should set a boolean flag  in the catch block when an error occurs, then display an appropriate Toast in `onProgressUpdate()`, `onPostExecute()`, or any of the other methods with UI access whenever the flag is `true`.

Comment: I don't understand that either... +1'ed it

Comment: Which Context should be passed to toast **getBaseContext()** or **getApplication()** Context?

Answer (score 17):

return from doInBackground as

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params){
    //some code
    try{
       //some code
     }catch(Exception e){
        return "Exception Caught";
     }
     return someValidResult;
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result){
    if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("Exception Caught")){
       //Display Toast
    }else{
       // // whatever you wana do with valid result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Write the following code where you have to show toast in `doInBackground()` method

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

public void run() {

  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Example for Toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   }
});
```

- BTW: if you are using `Fragments`, you need to call `runOnUiThread(...)` through your activity:

`getActivity().runOnUiThread(...)`

Answer (score 3):

You can display it in a method, that has access to the UI thread like `onPreExecute()`, `onProgressUpdate()` and `onPostExecute()`

Answer (score 3):

Create a handler object and execute all your Toast messages using that.

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    Handler handler=new handler();
    handler=  new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
    handler.post( new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Created a server socket",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

public void run() {

  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Example for Toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   }
});
```

is working perfectly fine to show toast in doInBackground() method

Answer (score 0):

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
 public void run() 
 {
    Toast.makeText(activity, "Toast teaxt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
void showError(final String err) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(downloadprogress.this, err + "error in download", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to declare anything related to Thread, then it must be outside the runOnUiThread() method, then only it is going to execute,

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Example for Toast "+i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }

        return "";
    }
```