# How to solve this error sending parameter to remote server android

Tags: android, parameters, send

I want to send parameter to remote server using HTTP Post, but I got some trouble, I didn't understand what's the error refers to.

here my error source code :

```
07-12 12:06:08.405: E/WindowManager(8381): Activity com.example.eranyoto.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41565338 that was originally added here
07-12 12:06:08.405: E/WindowManager(8381): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.eranyoto.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41565338 that was originally added here
07-12 12:06:08.405: E/WindowManager(8381):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:397)
07-12 12:06:08.405: E/WindowManager(8381):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:311)
07-12 12:06:08.405: E/WindowManager(8381):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
07-12 12:06:08.405: E/WindowManager(8381):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
07-12 12:06:08.405: E/WindowManager(8381):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:556)
07-12 12:06:08.405: E/WindowManager(8381):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
07-12 12:06:08.405: E/WindowManager(8381):  at com.example.eranyoto.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:311)
07-12 12:06:08.405: E/WindowManager(8381):  at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2606)
07-12 12:06:08.405: E/WindowManager(8381):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1045)
07-12 12:06:08.405: E/WindowManager(8381):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
07-12 12:06:08.405: E/WindowManager(8381):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
07-12 12:06:08.405: E/WindowManager(8381):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
07-12 12:06:08.405: E/WindowManager(8381):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java:156)
07-12 12:06:08.405: E/WindowManager(8381):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
07-12 12:06:08.405: E/WindowManager(8381):  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1280)
07-12 12:06:08.405: E/WindowManager(8381):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3067)
07-12 12:06:08.405: E/WindowManager(8381):  at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3968)
07-12 12:06:08.405: E/WindowManager(8381):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-12 12:06:08.405: E/WindowManager(8381):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-12 12:06:08.405: E/WindowManager(8381):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-12 12:06:08.405: E/WindowManager(8381):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
07-12 12:06:08.405: E/WindowManager(8381):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-12 12:06:08.405: E/WindowManager(8381):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-12 12:06:08.405: E/WindowManager(8381):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
07-12 12:06:08.405: E/WindowManager(8381):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
07-12 12:06:08.405: E/WindowManager(8381):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

my source code : http://pastebin.com/ihEdn7gv

```
public class Timeline extends Activity {
    //private ProgressBar pb;
    private String status;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_timeline);

        RadioButton rbtnlisting=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rbtnlisting);
        RadioButton rbtnclosing=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rbtnclosing);
        RadioButton rbtnprospek=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rbtnprospek);        
        final EditText edtstatus=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtstatus);
        Button btnpost=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnpost);

        edtstatus.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getBaseContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize( R.dimen.lbltitlelistviewitem));
        btnpost.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getBaseContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize( R.dimen.lbltitlelistviewitem));
        rbtnlisting.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getBaseContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize( R.dimen.lbltitlelistviewitem));
        rbtnclosing.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getBaseContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize( R.dimen.lbltitlelistviewitem));
        rbtnprospek.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getBaseContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize( R.dimen.lbltitlelistviewitem));

        btnpost.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {                           
                if (edtstatus.getText().length()>5) {
                    //pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    new MyAsyncTask().execute("ccc");   
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Your status is too short", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }           
            }
        });
    }

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{

        @Override
        //protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
        protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            postData(params[0]);
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Double result){
            //pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Code Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
            //pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
        }

        public void postData(String id) {
            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            EditText edtstatus=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtstatus);
            RadioButton rbtnlisting=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rbtnlisting);
            RadioButton rbtnclosing=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rbtnclosing);
            RadioButton rbtnprospek=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rbtnprospek);

            if (rbtnclosing.isSelected()) {status="Closing";}
            else if (rbtnprospek.isSelected()) {status="Prospek";}
            else if (rbtnlisting.isSelected()) {status="Listing";}          

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/dummy/insert.php");
            try {               
                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("idsales",OtherClass.getIdSales().toString()));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("jenis", status));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("remark", edtstatus.getText().toString()));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("path", "coba coba"));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Successfully posting status", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } 
            catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
        }

    }   
}
```

Comment: Post your `AsyncTask` code.

Comment: my posting question is already edited

Comment: @AgoengPutz you cannot touch ui from doInBackground

Comment: what do you mean cannot touch ?

Comment: @Raghunandan means you can't do `Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Successfully posting status", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` in `doInBackground`

Comment: I just wanna trace to know its error in doInBackground or not.

Comment: Yes what your doing is wrong. read asynctask docs

Comment: I have added it before in different source codes, it was working, I think the problem is not toast..

Comment: Even if you fix the current error you will end up getting another exception which indicates no update of ui from background thread

Comment: You can display it in a method, that has access to the UI thread like onPreExecute(), onProgressUpdate() and onPostExecute()

Comment: can you give me some hints ?

Comment: For more info see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13790351/how-to-show-toast-in-asynctask-in-doinbackground

Comment: @AgoengPutz what is `MainActivity.java` line 311. I guess you need to post MainActivity. Still you need to remove toast.