# How to Print Message when Json Response has no fileds?

Tags: android, json, toast

I am using this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/ for json parsing,and in my app response and everything works fine,but what if response has no filed,suppose as per this tutorial if it has reponse like {"contacts":""},it means no array so how to print toast if no fields there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per this example try this..

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    if(contacts == null || contacts.length() == 0){                
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       
    }

    // Dismiss the progress dialog
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
         pDialog.dismiss();          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (response=null)
Toast.maketext(this,"No response",Toast.lenght_long).show();
```

Comment: check example and tell me where can i add this line

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check if your `response` is **null** or with `length` **0**

```
if (response=null || response.length == 0 )
Toast.makeText(this,"No contacts found.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Getting JSON Array node
contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);
if(contacts == null || contacts.length() == 0){
    // Do your thing..
}
```

Comment: as per that tutorial where can i add this lines

Comment: In your GetContacts class which is an AsyncTask.

Comment: You will have to make your toast the UIThread, in this case onPostExecute

Comment: I gave you a hint, you can figure the rest out!
You could make doInBackground to return a list with contacts or a Boolean indicating if there are any contacts. And act on that onPostExecute

Comment: what if i need to add textview there?

Answer (score 0):

Try this as per example code

```
// Getting JSON Array node
contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);
if(contacts == null || contacts.length() == 0){
   // show toast in doinbackground using runOnUiThread
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {

                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                       }
                    });
}
```

Comment: Display `Toast` in `doInBackground` refer this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13790351/how-to-show-toast-in-asynctask-in-doinbackground](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13790351/how-to-show-toast-in-asynctask-in-doinbackground)