# Toast does not appears when thread completes its execution

Tags: android, multithreading, android-studio

I have a `AsyncTask<Task, Void, Boolean>` thread in my Android application. And I want to show message through `Toast.makeText()` when this thread completes its execution. For this I have added `Toask.makeText()` inside `if` as well as inside `else` of `doInBackground` method. The thread is completing its execution succesfully but the toast's message does not appears. So what can be the problem?

**Code:**

```
@Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Task... arg0) {
        try {

            Task task = arg0[0];

            QueryBuilder qb = new QueryBuilder();

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(qb.buildContactsSaveURL());

            StringEntity params =new StringEntity(qb.createTask(task));
            request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
            request.setEntity(params);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

            if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()<205)
            {
                /*this is the message inside if*/
                Toast.makeText(context, "inside -IF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                /*this is the message inside else*/
                Toast.makeText(context, "inside -ELSE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show toast in AsyncTask in doInBackground](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13790351/how-to-show-toast-in-asynctask-in-doinbackground)

Answer (score 3):

Toast work in **Main thread** you are trying to show Toast in **Background Thread** (doInBackground). Move your toast code to `onPostExecution` callaback and you will be able to see Toasts.

Comment: how can I call onPostExecution method? please show the code for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

The Task it is doing is in background, it won't show toast as it is in background.
Background tasks don't affect your UI or main thread.

Answer (score 0):

> The thread is completing its execution succesfully but the toast's
>   message does not appears

Because `doInBackground` method run on non-ui-Thread. and application only show Alert,Toast and update UI elements from UI-Thread only.

To show Toast from `doInBackground` wrap Toast related code inside `runOnUiThread` method

**OR**

return  `response` from `doInBackground` method and use `onPostExecute` method to show Toast.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by other people, you shouldn't have any UI related changes/activities on the background thread. Do it on the main thread which onPostExecute method does. Here's an example

```
private class DoSomethingTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //Do background process here. Make sure there are no UI related changes here
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void x) 
    {
        //Do UI related changes here
    }
}
```

Using your code:

```
private class DoSomethingTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    int statusCode;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Task... arg0) {
        try {

        Task task = arg0[0];

        QueryBuilder qb = new QueryBuilder();

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(qb.buildContactsSaveURL());

        StringEntity params =new StringEntity(qb.createTask(task));
        request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        request.setEntity(params);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
        statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void x) 
    {
        //Do UI related changes here

        if(statusCode < 205)
        {
            /*this is the message inside if*/
            Toast.makeText(context, "inside -IF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            /*this is the message inside else*/
            Toast.makeText(context, "inside -ELSE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!